# T-SQL select values close to specific date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've tables like this:

```
number    group              date
  1         1        2013-02-02 09:03:00.000
  1         2        2013-02-02 15:00:21.000
  1         2        2013-02-03 12:01:00.000
  2         3        2013-02-03 11:21:00.000
  2         1        2013-02-02 15:11:30.000
```

I need a query that will compare date with specific date(parameter) and return results like this:

If @param = '2013-02-03 00:00:00.000' results:

```
1  1  2013-02-02 15:00:21.000 
2  1  2013-02-02 15:11:30.000
```

If @param = '2013-02-04 00:00:00.000' results

```
1  2  2013-02-03 12:01:00.000
2  3  2013-02-03 11:21:00.000
```

Comment: You need the results from the previous day?

Comment: yes, but only the rows that are closest to parameter

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "closest to".

Comment: i mean my parameter - @param

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 or above, you can use a ranking function like [row_number](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
declare @param datetime = '2013-02-03 00:00:00.000'

;with topDate as
(
  select *
    , dateRank = row_number() over (partition by number order by [date] desc)
  from MyTable
  where [date] < @param
)
select number
  , [group]
  , [date]
from topDate
where dateRank = 1
order by number
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f0df/1) for your first parameter (it looks like you have a slight typo in your results but the fiddle looks correct to me).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what results should be shown, but if you need to select all data from your table meeting the criteria, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, (dateadd(dd, 1, date)))) = convert(DATETIME, @param, 120)
```

Starting from SQL Server 2008 you can use a different, simplified syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM Temp WHERE dateadd(dd, 1, cast(date AS DATE)) = convert(DATETIME, '2013-02-03 00:00:00.000', 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the last two dates before your parameter.  If so:

```
select top 2 t.*
from table t
where [date] < @param
order by [date] desc;
```

EDIT:

I notice that the first column is sequentially numbered, and not the original `number`.  The following query provides this:

```
select top 2 row_number() over (order by [date] desc) as [number],
       t.[group], t.[date]
from table t
where [date] < @param
order by [date] desc;
```